# C# Windows Service Hangfire Error : 1053(GlobalConfiguration connecting to database)

Tags: c#, hangfire

I've written a Windows Service in C# using HangFire. 
Service1 looks like :

```
    public Service1()
    {   
       InitializeComponent();
       GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-B90D804\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Leavingstone_Geocell_Students;Integrated Security=True");
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart5.txt");
        _server = new BackgroundJobServer(); 
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStop5.txt");
        _server.Dispose();
    }
```

But I keep getting Error 1053 from windows service when I try to install. saying that the service did not respond to the start or control reuqest in a timely fashion.

But If I take Out "`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-B90D804\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Leavingstone_Geocell_Students;Integrated Security=True");`" it works.

Also when I run  it into a debug mode from visual studio it also works without taking out GlobalConfiguration section. Windows service uses Local system account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've granted sql permission to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user and problem solved.